# on click handler fire event only once

Tags: jquery

I have this piece of jquery:

```
$('#team-members .team-thumb').on('click', function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        var member = $(this).data('member');
        $('#team-members .team-profiles').slideToggle();
        teamSlider.reloadSlider({
            startSlide: member,
            pager: false,
            adaptiveHeight: true
        });
        $('html,body').animate({
            scrollTop: $("#team-profiles").offset().top},
        'fast');
        $('.bx-viewport').prepend('<div id="slide-me"></div>');
    });
```

How do i make it only prepend this event once so on the second click it dosn't add it to the DOM:

```
$('.bx-viewport').prepend('<div id="slide-me"></div>');
```

Answer (score 4):

Use jQuery's [`one()` command:](http://api.jquery.com/one/)

```
$('#team-members .team-thumb').one('click', function(e){ ... }
```

> **Description**: Attach a handler to an event for the elements. The handler is executed at most once per element per event type.

Other than this built in command, you could always use a boolean flag:

```
var event_handler_enabled = true;
$('#team-members .team-thumb').one('click', function(e){
  if ( event_handler_enabled ){
    // code for handling click goes here
    event_handler_enabled = false; // ensure this code will not be executed again
  }   
}
```

I'd recommend the first option. There's no reason to re-invent the wheel. If jQuery has a built in method for executing a handler only once - use it! :)

Comment: Note that if you use `one` with delegation, "per element" refers to the delegate, not to the target

Answer (score 2):

You can do this inside the click event:

```
var $viewport = $('.bx-viewport');
if($viewport.find('#slide-me').length === 0)
     $viewport.prepend('<div id="slide-me"></div>');
```

- Cache the `bx-viewport` element first.
- Incase, `slide-me` is not inserted in the beginning of `bx-viewport` element yet, then prepend the element, else do nothing.

Comment: Yes - this would work. But it's not very intuitive for the next programmer who comes along to maintain the code :)

Comment: @Lix I find the logic readable and it has the upside that this won't append the container if it's already present through other means, and it will reappend the container if it disappears somehow. That being said, I still prefer your solution.